# different linspaces or aranges that all include exact 0.0

Tags: python, numpy

Is it easy to generate two linspace ranges going from a lower negative limit to an upper positive limit that both contain 0.0 as an exact value?

Here's an example how it fails:

```
>>> r1=np.arange(-.3,.6,.1)
>>> r2=np.arange(-.5,.5,.1)
>>> r1
array([ -3.00000000e-01,  -2.00000000e-01,  -1.00000000e-01,
         5.55111512e-17,   1.00000000e-01,   2.00000000e-01,
         3.00000000e-01,   4.00000000e-01,   5.00000000e-01])
>>> r2
array([ -5.00000000e-01,  -4.00000000e-01,  -3.00000000e-01,
        -2.00000000e-01,  -1.00000000e-01,  -1.11022302e-16,
         1.00000000e-01,   2.00000000e-01,   3.00000000e-01,
         4.00000000e-01])
>>> r1[3]
5.5511151231257827e-17
>>> r2[5]
-1.1102230246251565e-16
```

I'd like r1[3] and r2[5] to be exactly 0.0 (assuming IEEE-754). The only workaround I can see is generating the ranges [-x0,0[ and then appending [0,x1]. Is there a better way that's easier to read?

Comment: `numpy.arange(Decimal('-0.5'),Decimal('0.5'),Decimal('0.1'))` by using "Decimal" you can get around errors with floating point math

Comment: Why not `linspace`?

Comment: Wait a minute!  Is this about `linspace` or `arange`.  Your subject is confusing, even misleading.  But in either case, yes, you do need to generate numbers with a 0.0 starting point if you want that float to be exact.  There's too much float imprecision otherwise.

Comment: Yes, sorry - I tried both linspace and arange and they have the same problem. I opted to put the arange example in the post because it seems people are more familiar with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate an integer range and multiply by whatever scale factor:

```
r1 = np.arange(-3, 6) * 0.1
```

Or for a bit more precision (though it won't affect the 0), avoid a rounding step by dividing by the exact value of 10.0 instead of multiplying by the inexact value of 0.1:

```
r1 = np.arange(-3, 6) / 10.0
```

Using `arange` with floating-point arguments is generally a bad idea. It's usually better to use `numpy.linspace`, but if you need *exactly* 0 as one of the elements, `linspace` doesn't make strong enough promises:

```
>>> numpy.linspace(-2, 1, 148)[::49]
array([-2.00000000e+00, -1.00000000e+00, -2.22044605e-16,  1.00000000e+00])
>>> (numpy.arange(-2*49, 50) / 49)[::49]
array([-2., -1.,  0.,  1.])
```

Comment: if he uses `decimal.Decimal` I think it will "remove" the floating point errors

Comment: @JoranBeasley: It will also remove most of the benefit of NumPy, and only work for endpoints and steps that can be exactly represented in decimal. Also, `decimal.Decimal` is still floating-point, just adjustable-precision decimal floating point. Floating-point rounding still occurs.

Comment: I like this solution, simple and lots of scaling options, it will work particularly well for my problem of generating grids with varying extends that can be lined up.